# Sorting by an array's elements properties in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects which created from a custom class. The custom class have some attributes and i want to sort the array by one of these attributes? Is there an easy way to implement this on ruby, or should i code it from scratch?

Example:

```
class Example
  attr_accessor :id, :number

  def initialize(iid,no)
    @id = iid
    @number = no
  end
end

exarray = []
1000.times do |n|
  exarray[n] = Example.new(n,n+5)
end
```

Here i want to sort the exarray by its elements `number` attribute.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[sort_by](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#M002173) is probably the shortest option

```
exarray.sort_by {|x| x.number}
```

This also works

```
exarray.sort_by &:number
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to encapsulate this logic inside the class, implement a `<=>` method on your class, you can tell Ruby how to compare objects of this type. Here's a basic example:

```
class Example
  include Comparable  # optional, but might as well
  def <=>(other)
    this.number <=> other.number
  end
end
```

Now you can call `exarray.sort` and it will "just work."

---

Further reading:

- http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000244 (Array#sort)
- http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Comparable.html

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
exarray.sort { |a, b| a.number <=> b.number }
```

Comment: Always use sort_by instead of sort if you can. And you usually can.

Comment: @glen mcdonald: a little explanation might be nice. Two advantages of `sort_by` are that it is shorter and more concise and that it includes an implicit Schwartzian Transform to avoid computing expensive things for each comparison in the sort.