# Sorting select results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to sort `c.description` alphabetically but I'm not familiar with Ruby and can't seem to get `.sort` to work.

```
cakes.select do |cake|
  cake.categories.pluck(:id).any? do |ca| 
    category.self_and_descendant_ids.include? ca
  end.map { |c| { id: c.form_descriptor, name: "#{c.description}" } }
end
```

Comment: Can you give us an overview of how your data is laid out and what you are trying to do as a whole? This query can probably be simplified.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting by an array's elements properties in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059868/sorting-by-an-arrays-elements-properties-in-ruby)

Comment: To highlight a block of code indent it four spaces or select it and click on the {} icon above the code entry box. To highlight code that is within a sentence surround it with the backtick character (`), which often is a key below the escape key.

Comment: @Josh please describe what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe the code you wrote would function if you ran it in IRB. Could we have a better example of your data structure? You probably want to stay in the database for this. It's not clear where your "category" variable is coming from. The internal any? followed by a map won't work (map operates on an enumerable, any? returns a boolean).

Your pluck(:id) is an N+1 and will round-trip the to the database for every cake, not including whatever self_and_descendant_ids is doing - seems like a modeling problem since you could just associate categories with cakes and be done with any notion of descendants but this all conjecture without knowing more about your data or what you're modeling.

```
Categories.joins(:cakes)
          .where(cakes: { id: cake_ids })
          .order(description: :asc)
          .pluck(:form_descriptor, :description)
          .map { |id, name| { id: id, name: name } }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were to sort the descriptions alphabetically, I could use

`sorted_cakes = cakes.sort { |cake_a, cake_b| cake_a.description <=> cake_b.description }`

If you wanted them in reverse alphabetical order, you can change it to `cake_b.description <=> cake_a.description`

Comment: another option from @Sara's recommendation is to use `cakes.sort_by { |cake| cake.description }`

Answer (score 0):

Why not sort it before traversing? You can do like

```rb
cakes.select do |cake|
  cake.categories.order('categories.description ASC').pluck(:id).any? do |ca| 
    category.self_and_descendant_ids.include? ca
  end.map { |c| { id: c.form_descriptor, name: "#{c.description}" } }
end
```